In Cloudpage SmartCapture Form can I limit calendar dates to the first 30 days post the initial appointment date only?
I have a date picking option in Salesforce Cloudpages that I want to limit/restrict the choice of calendar dates to 30 days after the initial appointment date. I have the appointment_date in a DE that would be used as the point of reference for the initial appointment but I dont appear to be able to set a min or max for the options in the date picker.
<div class="sc-formfield-input date-dropdown-select-boxes" data-pattern="month day year">
 <input type="text" id="change_date" name="change_date" class="hidden hidden-field" data-field-type="Text" readonly="readonly" aria-hidden="true">

 <select class="select month" id="change_date_month">
  <option id="MM" value="" selected="selected">MM</option>

  <option id="01" value="01">01</option>

  <option id="02" value="02">02</option>

  <option id="03" value="03">03</option>

  <option id="04" value="04">04</option>

  <option id="05" value="05">05</option>

  <option id="06" value="06">06</option>

  <option id="07" value="07">07</option>

  <option id="08" value="08">08</option>

  <option id="09" value="09">09</option>

  <option id="10" value="10">10</option>

  <option id="11" value="11">11</option>

  <option id="12" value="12">12</option>

 </select>

 <select class="select day" id="change_date_day">
  <option id="DD" value="" selected="selected">DD</option>

  <option id="01" value="01">01</option>

  <option id="02" value="02">02</option>

  <option id="03" value="03">03</option>

  <option id="04" value="04">04</option>

  <option id="05" value="05">05</option>

  <option id="06" value="06">06</option>

  <option id="07" value="07">07</option>

  <option id="08" value="08">08</option>

  <option id="09" value="09">09</option>

  <option id="10" value="10">10</option>

  <option id="11" value="11">11</option>

  <option id="12" value="12">12</option>

  <option id="13" value="13">13</option>

  <option id="14" value="14">14</option>

  <option id="15" value="15">15</option>

  <option id="16" value="16">16</option>

  <option id="17" value="17">17</option>

  <option id="18" value="18">18</option>

  <option id="19" value="19">19</option>

  <option id="20" value="20">20</option>

  <option id="21" value="21">21</option>

  <option id="22" value="22">22</option>

  <option id="23" value="23">23</option>

  <option id="24" value="24">24</option>

  <option id="25" value="25">25</option>

  <option id="26" value="26">26</option>

  <option id="27" value="27">27</option>

  <option id="28" value="28">28</option>

  <option id="29" value="29">29</option>

  <option id="30" value="30">30</option>

  <option id="31" value="31">31</option>

 </select>

 <select class="select year" id="change_date_year">
  <option id="YYYY" value="" selected="selected">YYYY</option>

  <option id="2022" value="2022">2022</option>

  <option id="2023" value="2023">2023</option>

  <option id="2024" value="2024">2024</option>

  <option id="2025" value="2025">2025</option>

  <option id="2026" value="2026">2026</option>



 </select>

</div>

